# Problema con SqlException: El nombre de objeto no es válido

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy iniciando un proyecto mvc web con .net6.0 e intentando mostrar en una vista los registros recuperados de un dbset del dbcontext. La conexión la paso en appsettings.json y defino el contexto en program.cs. He revisado y parece que se conecta bien a la base de datos pero en el controlador (UsuariosControler.cs) al solicitar los datos al contexto para pasarlos a la vista falla con el mensaje **El nombre de objeto 'Usuarios' no es válido**. Si alguien puede darse cuenta donde está el error por favor, le agradecería mucho.

Código de appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "cnnValijas": "server=.;database=DB_VALIJA;Integrated Security=True;Trust Server Certificate=true"
    }
  }
```

Código de program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ValijasDBContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("cnnValijas")));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Usuarios}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Código del DBContext:

```
public class ValijasDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ValijasDBContext(DbContextOptions<ValijasDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

Código del modelo:

```
    public class Usuario
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Nombre Usuario")]
        public string Nombres { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Apellidos { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Correo { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Clave { get; set; } = null!;
        public int IdOrigen { get; set; }
        public int IdRol { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Dirección")] 
        public string Direccion { get; set; } = null!;
        [Display(Name = "Teléfono")]
        public string Telefono { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Activo { get; set; } = null!;
        public string ConfirmarClave { get; set; } = null!;
        [Display(Name = "Orígen")] 
        public string Nombre_Origen { get; set; } = null!;
        [Display(Name = "Rol")] 
        public string Descripcion_Rol { get; set; } = null!;
        [Display(Name = "Nombre Usuario")] 
        public string Nombre_Usuario { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Trozo de código del controlador: (Es justamente en el método Index donde falla)

```
public class UsuariosController : Controller
 {
     private readonly ValijasDBContext _context;

     public UsuariosController(ValijasDBContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     }

     // GET: Usuarios
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
     {
         return _context.Usuarios != null ? 
                       View(await _context.Usuarios.ToListAsync()) :
                       Problem("Entity set 'ValijasDBContext.Usuarios'  is null.");
     }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has aplicado `migrations` y actualizado la base de datos?